# Sharepoint 2010 - MS Word Content Controls Editing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word

I have a workflow in SP2010 that updates a Word template using content controls. This all works fine until someone wants to edit the text within the content control. Whilst they can add to it and delete it they cannot edit the actual text that has been passed in from Sharepoint.

What can I do to make this content editable? It seems weird that it can be delete and added to but not edited - my inital thought is that is was a permissions problem but if that was the case, adding and deleting would also be blocked.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your question is limited and cannot be answered with this info. Please update the code you use to udate content in the content control if you got any. Or atleast post a sample document generated which is having the problem mentioned in your question.

Comment: The "code" is within a workflow, so it's not really possible to post, otherwise I would have. Sample document is also difficult as I am bound by confidentiality.

Comment: In that case it is really up to you to think of ways that you could communicate what you are doing. Could you at least unzip the word document and post the XML (w:sdt I guess) that represents the content control. Are you populating the control by populating a custom XML part and pointing the control to the XPATH, or doing it directly?